# Kubuntu can't connect to WIFI

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, kubuntu, kde

First of all, I would like to say that I have searched and tried everything suggested and still having this problem. I am unable to connect to any wifi available, I have tried my home wifi and my hotspot but KDE Daemon constantly keeps asking for network authentication. My computer has dual-boot with Windows 10 and I have no problems with the wifi on my Windows. I have unchecked the KDE wallet, restarted the network service nothing helped. I have used Kubuntu for the last 6 and everything was fine the first time it happened. I deleted and reinstalled Network manager and made my WiFi open cus I thought maybe the encryptions were the problem still nothing.

Comment: Any helpful https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/post/9129728/   here?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a fix, but I've recently started experiencing the same. I've also found I've no problem connecting to unsecured wifi networks, but anything secured makes this happen :\

Comment: I can't connect to unsecured

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 edited and uploaded a pic

Comment: Please don't post terminal screenshots. You can copy text from a terminal.

Comment: And what is the Kubuntu version and kernel version `uname -a`? Also please provide output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @Pilot6 I fixed it...based on the results I got from the output of the second command. Thank you very much for the helping me fix the problem and also i learned some new stuff i did not know before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments on the original question, your problem differs from mine, so it's pretty unlikely this will help you, but in case it helps anyone else:

I booted into a linux USB, connected to a secured wifi on there, then simply rebooted into my installed version. (Wifi autoconnected as it had been working for me before.)

I have *no* idea why or how it worked for me, but I saw [someone else report that work for them](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=218671), though retroactively thought it might've been a kernel upgrade. I figured there was little risk or harm in trying the bootable, though, and it helped me.

Comment: it was the kernel version and the wifi driver, i booted an alder version and everything works fine.I am curious on what exactly is the the problem in more details so i will do more digging.

Comment: While I appreciate the extra points for being marked as the best answer, it sounds like your solution is different. If you fix your own problem without/before contribution from others, you're more than welcome to write up your own "response" and accept that - it can be useful for anyone else coming across the page :)